# Set proxyServer for Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Following the documentation of Pupetter this is the way to set a proxy for incognito context.

```
    const context = await this.browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext({
      proxyServer: `http://${proxy.host}:${proxy.port}`,
    });
```

however when checking ip on https://whatismyipaddress.com/, it still shows my local ip.

I tried to use *puppeteer-page-proxy* but it's being blocked by Cloudlfare because of the implementation used.

setting proxy using pupeteer args works fine, but for my use case i need it to rotate proxies for every request, without recreating the browser itself